# R coding issue (picking certain rows for valuation purposes)

Tags: r, dataset, rows

I wanted to ask if anyone could please help me with this code. I am trying to build an analytic script which will compute all the ratios for the company. I am using R studio. 
I am having trouble with selecting certain rows. For instance, if I want to compute EBITDA/Sales or Revenue, I need to add a certain number of rows from that dataset and divide it by the first one.
I am able to do that for the ones which only involve singular rows.

How do I do that? My code is attached.

```
#Ratio Analytics Investment Banking Program
#implement libraries
library(quantmod)
library(stockPortfolio)
library(tseries)
library(FinCal)
#downloading data
getSymbols('BHP')
getFin('BHP') #env.class
#plot the data
plot(BHP$BHP.Adjusted)

income<-viewFin(BHP.f, "IS","A") #annual income statement
balancesheet<-viewFin(BHP.f,"BS","A")
income[is.na(income)]<-0
balancesheet[is.na(balancesheet)]<-0
View(balancesheet) #balancesheet
View(income)      #incomestatement
#calcualting the ratios for the company underconsideration

#finding gross profit margin
income1<-data.frame(income)
gpm<-income1[5,1]/income1[1,1] #gross profit margin
#compute EBITDA
ebitda<-income1[(16,17,18),1]/income1[1,1]
```

Error: unexpected ',' in "ebitda<-income1[(16,"

But, whenever I run the script it gives me an error. 
Any help here would be much appreciated.
Thank you everyone
Regards

Comment: Please paste the error into your question - it will make it a lot more likely that you will get help.  Also, your last two lines are the same.  For simplicity, just include one.

Comment: Hello Bryan, My only concern is how do I pick certain rows from a data set which I need for one calculation? I want to add certain rows (like 16,17,18) from the first column. I am able to do that for the ones for which there is only one row needed but what should I do when I need to take in to account multiple rows. Hopefully that should give a bit of hint as to what I am asking.

Comment: Ah, with your edit, I see you need a `c` as in `c(16, 17, 18)` which you need to do to select more than one row.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I did try that but its dividing individually. So, if I could add those rows and than have them divided by first row and first column? Is that something I can do?

Comment: > a<-sum(income1[c(16,17,18),1])/income1[1,1] I did this and it did the trick . Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
income1[(16,17,18),1]/income1[1,1]
```

to

```
income1[c(16,17,18,1)]/income1[c(1,1)]
```

And if income is a vector, then you'll need to change them all

```
gpm<-income1[5,1]/income1[1,1]
# to
gpm<-income1[c(5,1)]/income1[c(1,1)]
```

Comment: No problem. But also, are you sure you should be changing those NA values to zero?

Comment: From the source, that's what I am assuming. If it contains nothing but NA it should be 0. I am new to R so I am not sure if that's going to deteriorate the results. What do you think I should do?